# Build or Run docker image error : CreateComputeSystem - Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service

Tags: windows, docker, docker-build, windows-server-2019, docker-run

i got this error on windows server 2019 standard running docker and no idea how to solve it. Running windows container with process isolation. Memory is always max 40% (32Gb), CPU always below 20% and disks lot of space (250Gb free).

Running an official container like : `docker run -d --rm -p 8080:80 --name test mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp`

Got this error after extracting phase and start of container :

`C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: CreateComputeSystem ba698710f7bff4d46dce2ee65453b9da143195770b93cf82f8bb3818fca70174: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service. (extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"ba698710f7bff4d46dce2ee65453b9da143195770b93cf82f8bb3818fca70174","Owner":"docker","VolumePath":"\\\\?\\Volume{61d19b2c-50e1-4dd5-9257-9c67998f1123}","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\ba698710f7bff4d46dce2ee65453b9da143195770b93cf82f8bb3818fca70174","Layers":[{"ID":"05435bc5-50b1-5044-9210-12d7ab180470","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\84fc4324bf3d2de92b5f9c0a80e238bc3b3f1fdbe0fea13b7a35146069c21663"},{"ID":"3f1c6cd1-b66d-5d8d-aa2e-d11e489b74fe","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\11d9c87c3490cf087488aaf21a3c88b45c68273ea270c6f850261583715cf241"},{"ID":"655918d6-84bb-5633-8bb2-981f3a29e3c6","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\1f11a5340a1c13ef658355b9e30f7794ee398fb863105d6e18b48bd8a4687f79"},{"ID":"41893d4a-0704-50df-8f4e-41cad4480d3e","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\36296cba828c68663184ddd5e75f5084ce59b755fcc9025845fe516782b2e243"},{"ID":"dc4a1317-f05d-5470-847d-d1e4bd029e6d","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\8293bbc58e2c9c7da089187afd6cbf0e22b1bcb27cadc3e569542e324733ef82"},{"ID":"6f247d11-4160-56dc-9dbe-b40a4b67d151","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\d9ba1e3f6cffcc5f69e2d2265a7539a0e4aff9b4f8f86e3edc3ff5b4026a584b"},{"ID":"5f54a86d-b6e0-5f1c-977d-dc7bba046d7e","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\9beb006814b54bda1f7afa7a0f2870a4a970ef624ab6d2bffec4e27f2b749d6e"},{"ID":"03a39db9-584f-5d5b-8bbc-95883aa2af8b","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\38ad1eb3b36d16eb77e6264daca47fad96080cb9596aa6aeb8c6d269ffbead89"},{"ID":"bffe53fb-2619-5d30-ae46-da6f759a87ed","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\d4b5eaee9002c7b73dd7a72880c9caa3a39b7ef5c304b19e7c0a732c01b2a4bb"},{"ID":"aaec8c93-d215-59d6-99e2-001f38fa3ee3","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\34ccac695ab1683cc21309e94c64110476d45b07b69b6956da9e795c31f6b815"}],"HostName":"ba698710f7bf","HvPartition":false,"EndpointList":["9070F572-5CDD-4CCE-8C7E-218F0BA2F221"],"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}).`

```
Server: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.11
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       6112046bc9
  Built:            11/13/2019 07:49:53
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to registry,
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\NDIS\IfTypes\24`
and set `ifUsedNetLuidIndices` to `01`
and then restart the computer.

Comment: Zahra, yes I did that initially but that was temporary fix and index was going very high quickly each time docker service was restarted. You don't need to restart computer just docker service by the way. I fixed it finally with August 2020 Windows server 2019 updates and installing VMware tools 11.1.1